# How can pixels display continuous data?

Tags: vector-graphics, pixels

I am currently playing around with procedurally-generating Sierpinski triangles in Terraria but I have encountered a problem.

As you can see in the image below, the dimensions of the triangles are not discrete and so I am ending up with skew triangles which overlap.

[image]
[image]

Clearly it is possible to display these kinds of shapes using discrete pixels, so my question is: how do my graphics display these triangles correctly, and how can I apply this to what I'm currently doing?

Comment: You might get a better result by rendering to a larger (double or quadruple) pixel dimension canvas. I *think* this will have the effect of increasing the sample rate. Your image is being mangled by rounding errors. Note that the vertical resolution of your image is half that of your comparison image. This also presumes you are using the appropriate data types.

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem